# not operator query cypher neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, conditional-operator

I have **Players** and **Games** nodes types .... player can invite other player to a game.
once a player **A** will invite player **B** it will look like that:

```
A-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-B , game.initiator = ID(A) , game.state = 'INVITE'
```

As you can see I am using a property inside the game to represent whom invited whom.
game can be in many states.

for a given player I need a query to retrieve all his games except this which in state = INVITE and he initiate them.

Tried the following but without success even though it sound like easy case:

```
  START playerA = node() 
  match playerA-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-otherPlayer 
  where not(game.state = 'INVITE' and game.initiator = ID(playerA)) 
  return game
```

for example:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/fkpoht

```
START playerB = node(15) 
MATCH playerB-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-PlayerA
WHERE NOT (game.state = 'INVITE' AND game.initiator = ID(playerB)) 
RETURN game
```

Why the above query doesn't return the game? the first condition is true the sec is false not(true&false) = true...

What is the way to do this simple query right? your answer are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
START playerA = node(1) 
MATCH playerA-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-otherPlayer 
WHERE (game.state='INVITE' AND game.initiator <> 1) OR (game.state<>'INVITE') 
RETURN game
```

Comment: In your query every game with state <> INVITE will not returned this is not what I need.

Comment: What do you mean you can't try it? all the required game properties for the query are exist...

Comment: K I could see the console properties fine now. Couldn't figure out the NOT but edited my query with a workaround

Comment: Ya wanted it without the OR .. performance thing.. but I guess the NOT operator not functioned as it should be...

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to retrieve all his games, which he initiate them and state `not INVITE` :

```
 START playerA = node() 
 MATCH playerA-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-otherPlayer 
 WHERE (game.initiator = ID(playerA)) AND NOT (game.state = 'INVITE')
 RETURN game
```

Comment: I want all the games except these which in (INVITE state & he initiate them)

Comment: `START playerA = node() 
 MATCH playerA-[:INTERACT]->game<-[:INTERACT]-otherPlayer 
 WHERE NOT (game.initiator = ID(playerA)) AND NOT (game.state = 'INVITE')
 RETURN game`

Comment: In your query any game which in INVITE state || playerA initiate will not return. this is not what I need.

Comment: I don't want games which -> (game.state = 'INVITE' and game.initiator = ID(playerA)) and I don't understand why I can't just wrap it in NOT operator...